# regexp R how to find <U00BF>

Tags: regex, r

How to find  using regular expressions?
How to write correctly?

I have for example the sentence like this:

```
Despite their ubiquity and importance in achieving high perfor<U+00BF>mance in modern processors...
```

and I just want to remove `<U+00BF>`, I've tried the following:

```
sentence2 = gsub("<U00BF>", "", sentence2)
```

Comment: The command you provided doesn't work for you? Can you give a sample string you're trying to "gsub"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand you are trying to remove the inverted question mark `¿` from a string.

You can use the `\x` notation to match hexadecimal values or a literal:

```
sentence2 <- "¿Donde?"
gsub("\\xBF", "", sentence2)  
// or
// gsub("\\xBF", "", sentence2, perl=T)
// or
// gsub("¿", "", sentence2)
```

Here is a [demo](http://ideone.com/w2y2TR)

To just remove the `<U+00BF>`, you need to escape `+`:

```
sentence2 <- "Despite their ubiquity and importance in achieving high perfor<U+00BF>mance in modern processors..."
gsub("<U\\+00BF>", "", sentence2)
```

See [this demo](http://ideone.com/PuEB8Z)

Comment: No, I didn't know before that it mean the inverted question mark , I have for example the sentence like this "Despite their ubiquity and importance in achieving high perfor<U+00BF>mance in modern processors..." and I just want to remove "<U+00BF>"